Why did my CR 2032 CMOS battery with reversed polarity discharge when connected?
I own an Intel NUC which we use as a HTPC.  It stays turned off most of the time minus game day/movie nights. It by default uses a JST connector standard polarity CR 2032 3V battery. I ordered a replacement battery online to replace the old degraded battery which led to CMOS errors and received a reversed polarity one (connectors reversed I did not know) since the battery had a yellow jacket around it for short protection in tight spaces. After connecting the new reversed battery about a day later I got a CMOS reset error while booting which led to further investigation and realized the battery had the incorrect polarity than what the NUC used.
Additionally, the NUC is on a not-so-great circuit with a ground leakage problem, so as long as the wall switch is on and if you touch the metal bits of the NUC or any other device one can feel a light current, including the USB port which has shocked me multiple times. Normal polarity batteries stay fine though they don't degrade.
Why did the battery discharge from solid 3.28V to 0.5V in one day?

Short answer is that they likely relied on how you can't put a normal battery in that socket upside-down for the reverse polarity protection instead of a diode or ideal diode circuit.  I'm curious to see the backwards battery you bought.  Can you post a link?

@SteKulov The battery described is a CR2032 wrapped in heat-shrink tubing with two spot-welded wires going to a small connector. This is common in laptops, since it saves board space and that the coin cell holders may require additional handling during board assembly. The polarity was either swapped at the connector or at the battery.

@user71659 Oh OK. I googled “laptop CR2032” and after seeing an image now understand much better. Thanks.

As the name CMOS battery already indicates, most semiconductors inside a PC are made using some sort of CMOS process. In a classic bulk CMOS process the transistor design looks like this:

(SOURCE: https://semiconductor.samsung.com/emea/support/tools-resources/dictionary/semiconductor-glossary-cmos/)
The bulk connections (B) of the NMOS and PMOS are connected to GND and VDD respectively. As you can see, the PMOS transistors are embedded in a n-doped well that sits inside the otherwise p-doped chip. The boundary between these two wells forms a diode. During normal operation, the p substrate of the wafer is connected to ground and the n-well connected to the positive supply (VDD. This way, the pn junction of that diode is in reverse operation and will block.
If you accidentally reverse power this circuit, that diode between GND and VDD will be conductive and essentially short out your battery.
You can test this yourself with almost any digital IC. (E.g. an ATmega microcontroller which sits on a simple Arduino). If you remove the IC from the circuit and measure the diode voltage using a multimeter in "Diode Mode", you will measure ~0.6V from GND to VDD. These are the intrinsic diodes and ESD protection diodes inside the device.
In addition to that effect, most Pins on a semiconductor are protected by some sort of ESD protection. This is also usually a diode between the pin and ground, that is in reverse polarity during normal operation. These protection diodes also conduct current when connected in reverse.
Coin cell batteries usually have a quite high intrinsic resistance. Therefore, they don't deliver much current when shorted. This most likely prevented anything from being actually damaged. If you would connect some other voltage source in reverse, there is a high chance of actually damaging the device.
